# code in g:message is not resolved

Tags: grails, internationalization, gsp

I am trying to understand why this is  not working :

`<g:set var="testvar" value="${'label.' + controller.computeLabel()}"/>`

`<g:message code="${testvar}"/>`

The output for this is (assuming that controller.computeLabel() returns "computed.label"):

`label.computed.label`

How can I force g:message to resolve the code attribute ?

Thank you !!

Comment: Does `label.computed.label` exists in `message.properties`?

Comment: yes it does.. when hardcoded it works..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming a lot with the statement of:

> Assuming that contoller.computeLabel() returns "computed.label"

Calling a controller inline like that in your GSP isn't going to behave the way you expect. In fact, it's wrong on many levels. **You should not be doing it**.

Instead, whatever controller is rendering the GSP should be providing the information in the model instead. So, you would end up with something like this:

```
<g:set var="testvar" value="${'label.' + valueFromModel}"/>
```

Approaching the problem this way, and using MVC correctly will solve your issue.

Without more information about the specifics of your situation it's impossible to give you a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

I feel dumb now... the labels were not matching.

It is working fine.